# UILocalNotifications fires without sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification, audio

Um making a local notifications and every thing is great, but no sound even I've set the sound name property with default notification sound name.
P.S: The sound is not working on simulator nor device.

This is my code..

```
UILocalNotification *aNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                aNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                aNotification.alertBody = _reminderTitle.text;
                aNotification.alertAction = @"Show me!";
                aNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
                aNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1;
```

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:aNotification];`

So Any ideas ? :)

Comment: Is your device on mute?

Comment: nop, what about simulator ?

Comment: possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532706/why-doesnt-my-uilocalnotification-play-any-sound?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Your simulator is probably muted.

Go to System Preferences -> Sound -> Sound Effects -> Check "Play user interface sound effects"

Comment: You mean I can't hear my notifications sound on simulator ?
I can't test it on simulator ?

Comment: You can, you need to unmute the simulator first using what I've just told you.

Comment: It was checked but no yet sound !!

Answer (score 0):

If the notification fires while the app is running, you wont hear a sound, you need to be out of the app to hear it.